# Merge a feature made of multiple commits along time into another project

Tags: git

There's a feature `tennis` made of multiple commits along the time, and I need to merge that feature into **another** project.

Consider this timeline:

```
- x - tennisV1 - x - x - tennisV2 - x - tennisV3 - x - x - x - x - x - tennisV4
```

I want this:

```
- tennisV1 - tennisV2 - tennisV3 - tennisV4
```

How can I do that?

I was thinking about showing the diff of all those commits merged to help me, but I don't know how to do that without showing changes of non-related commits in between (*x commits*).

I'm using git and also bitbucket so if there's something visual there it would be nice too.

Comment: Sounds like cherry-picking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like melpomene suggests in comment, it's pretty much the typical job of the `cherry-pick` command :

```
# let's checkout the target branch, where you want to put the tennis commits
git checkout <yourTargetBranch>

# and now instead of merging we only take what's needed
git cherry-pick tennisV1 tennisV2 tennisV3 tennisV4
```

In-between commits (x in your schema) won't come along, only the ones you picked.